# Setting up C++ and MinGW in VS Code: 16 bit Unsupported?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to follow this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp but when I try to run a program I get this error for an unsupported 16 bit application. I found an older question on here from previous versions of the compiler, but what they had didn't quite work for me. The error message is below.

"This version of C:\Users\jvgro\OneDrive\CProjects\main.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher."

I was using the command g++ main.cpp and then running the main.exe file generated. Not quite sure what to do and thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What is your windows and MinGW versions?

Comment: ***when I try to run a program I get this error for an unsupported 16 bit application.*** You can't run a 16 bit application on 64 bit windows without an emulator like dosbox. I question why you are creating a 16 bit executable.

Comment: @drescherjm that is exactly my question too! I have the current version of Windows 11 and followed the link to installer here, https://www.msys2.org/, used the precise install commands they mentioned.